# How to generate an image of a leaflet drawn map (like a printscreen)

Tags: php, leaflet

I'm using leaflet to draw maps and put misc layers on top of them.

I want to be able to create "print screens" of the maps in an automated fashion.

I know that first task is client side and second one is server side but I would like to know the steps to achieve this. For the server side I need solutions in PHP

For better understanding what I'm asking, think of a use case which could be generating reports which include images of maps

Answer (score 2):

See the ["Print/export" section in the list of Leaflet plugins](http://leafletjs.com/plugins.html#printexport).

Alternatively, use a [headless web browser](https://github.com/dhamaniasad/HeadlessBrowsers) such as [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/), that will allow you to load webpages without a graphical interface and take screenshots of them.